# sample php eclipse luna project

Tags: php, html, eclipse

i created a new php project called Small App and have one file in there, the index.html is a login page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Log In here</title>
   </head>
  <body>
 <form  action="loggedin.html" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form-login">
    <table>
    </tbody>          
       <tr>
         <td valign="top"> 
           <label for="name">UserName</label> 
         </td>                   
         <td valign="top"> 
           <input required placeholder="username" type="text" name="username"/>
         </td> 
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
         </td>              
         <td valign="top"> 
            <input required placeholder="password" type="password" name="password"/>
         </td> 
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td valign="top">
            <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>               
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">            
         </td>                                                                                                                                                  
       <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
          </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i go from here setting eclipe up to display this when I click run?
i am totally new to this

when i click run i get:
[image]

Comment: Just upload to web server & run in browser. By the way, Eclipse is not a good PHP IDE in my opinion.

Comment: and forget about `valign`, use CSS instead (there is an extra `</tbody>` too)

Comment: thanks all, i'll get to  the css, and i just want to do a once off small app, so any ide will do :)

Comment: anybody knows where can i download a working sample web project please?